# $u_n=\frac{n!e^n}{n^n\sqrt n}$ how to show that $v_n=log(u_{n+1})-log{(u_n)}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis

Let be $u_n=\frac{n!e^n}{n^n\sqrt n}$ I want to show that the series associated with the sequence $v_n=log(u_{n+1})-log{(u_n)}$ converges.

I did

\begin{align*}v_n&=log(\frac{(n+1)!e^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}\sqrt {n+1}})-log(\frac{n!e^n}{n^n\sqrt n})\\
&=-(n+1)^2log(\frac{(n+1)!(n+1)}{\sqrt {n+1}})+n^2log(\frac{(n)!(n)}{\sqrt {n}})
\end{align*}

But no idea where to go then...

Comment: hint: $\log (a) - \log(b) = \log(a/b)$, so you only have to show that $\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}$ converges to some positive number.

Comment: Note $\log$ looks better than $log$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is definitely wrong. Try the quotient first if logarithms are too alien, since $\ln a-\ln b=\ln\frac ab$.

$$
\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = \frac{(n+1)!e^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}}·\frac{n^n\sqrt{n}}{n!e^n}
=\frac{(n+1)·e·n^n·\sqrt{n}}{(n+1)^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{e}{(1+\frac1n)^{n+\frac12}}
$$